# How can a SOCKS5 proxy know client's datetime?

Tags: http, proxy, time, socks5

It seems that SOCKS5 proxies somehow know the client's timezone (at least) or maybe even the precise datetime. I determined this because the proxy tears the connection in case the local timezone on the client machine is UTC, but the proxy works well if the client timezone is set to GMT+3.
I checked the request that is sent via https://httpbin.org/anything : it doesn't contain the `Date:` header. Actually the request doesn't contain much at all:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip, br", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/58.0.3029.83 Mobile/14D27 Safari/602.1", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5ef44607-d2e19be825cf096c4f4facbc"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "GET", 
  "origin": "180.6.40.101", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

So could you give me a hint on how SOCKS5 proxies can determine client's timezone or local time?

Comment: I  doubt your description in that the difference is due to the datetime. A remote SOCKS proxy cannot determine the time settings on the local machine and thus can also not act on these. Could you please provide a way for others to reproduce what you are seeing?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, sorry, I can't provide a reproducer because this is a private proxy with authentication by IP address. Why else can be this difference you think? The proxy provider states explicitly that the time on the client machine must be UTC for the proxy to work, while I want to emulate this to account for different proxy providers.

Comment: The proxy access itself contains no time information. I don't know if there is something more to the proxy, i.e. like some portal where one need to login or some local app which provides the access to the proxy.